# list of lists with random number of elements each, how to align same elements in the same column?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

If you have list of lists with a random number of random elements each, how would you create a matrix such that same elements appear in the same column?

Every row has at least one element/column but different rows can have different numbers of elements/colums. Every element appears at most once per row.

Elements do not have to keep their original column but should appear in minimal distance to their original column in the resulting matrix.

Every element x that appears before element y in the input must also appear before y in the output.

For example:

```
a|c
a|b|c
c|e
a|d|e
b|d
```

should afterwards look like this:

```
a| |c| | 
a|b|c| | 
 | |c| |e
a| | |d|e
 |b| |d|
```

This was just a simple example, any positive number of colums and positive number of elements per column should be covered.

What would be an efficient algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Go through your data once, constructing a graph where each element is a node and there should be a directed edge between each element and the element appearing directly after that element.

Then do a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the graph:

> A topological sort or topological ordering of a directed graph is a linear ordering of its vertices such that for every directed edge uv from vertex u to vertex v, u comes before v in the ordering. For instance, the vertices of the graph may represent tasks to be performed, and the edges may represent constraints that one task must be performed before another; in this application, a topological ordering is just a valid sequence for the tasks.

This would return an ordered list of elements which would correspond to the ordering of the elements into columns.

Comment: Thanks, does this minimize the deviation from the original distances between elements?

Comment: This mainly strives to maintains the order of the elements (if `a|b` appears in the input, `b` always appear after `a` in the output), assuming this is actually possible, so this may not be exactly what you're after. I may have missed the "minimal distance" requirement, though I'm also not entirely sure exactly what distance you're talking about - though one may certainly be able to do the topological sort in such a way to minimize this distance.

Comment: Actually I understand what you mean by trying to minimize the distance to the original column, but this may conflict with the result of the topological sort, i.e. if `a|b` appears in the input, minimizing the distance may involve putting `b` before `a`, which conflicts with topological sort, which will always put `a` before `b`. So no, it doesn't really strive to minimize that distance (it may *in general* give a good distance, but there will certainly be exceptions).

Comment: I mean minimizing the distance while still adhering to all other constraints as there are still different distances possible it seems.